# Need to divide a single VF page into multiple tabs

Tags: visualforce, tab

I have a query. I have single vf page which is having 15 fields. Is it possible to divide that page into 3 tabs and assign 5 fields to each of it.

If Yes, can anyone please provide me some sample.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [apex:tab (doc)](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_tab.htm)

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" id="thePage">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="theTabPanel">
       <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne">
           <apex:outputField valie="{!Account.Name}" />
       </apex:tab>
       <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab>
       </apex:tabPanel>
       <apex:tab label="Three" name="name3" id="tabThree">content for tab three</apex:tab>
     </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```